# Will ResearchGate eventually find and create links to my publications?

Tags: publications, social-media

I have many publications in my profile that I had to add manually, but ResearchGate seems not to recognize any of them sufficiently to create links to the online full text (and other info) that is readily available for all of them (Google Scholar, for example has links to every one of them).

Will ResearchGate eventually find and connect these publications? (Is adding this information manually myself the only option?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ResearchGate does not support this feature, and has no current plans to do so.

The only way to attach information to publications that ResearchGate must be added manually (because ResearchGate fails to find them) is to add that information manually for each publication as well.

Answer (score 2):

ResearchGate will try to suggest papers that closely relates to your name provided. It will mostly suggest papers whose details are in its own repository (and probably some others). It does not have an effective crawler like Google Scholar.

I would consider adding them manually to be the better option.

Comment: Adding manually is not practical. So RG is a dead end for publications it doesn't already have in its own repository then? I guess I'm unclear on why anyone would use RG (say, over Google Scholar): it seems to rely on people doing all the work of posting all of the details of each of their own publications.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. Well, kind of. I just update my publication in RG each time it is published. RG is just an additional exposure.  Furthermore, it provides additional reviews and comments for the publication that Google Scholar doesn't support. It not like it is to be used *over* Google Scholar, but alongside it.

Comment: @raxa Why is adding publications manually not practical? You can use DOIs and a few other things to speed up the data entry aspects.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Precisely